# how to make moving spinner's edges rounded css

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions, loader

[**Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/4yL3rp38/5/) is my fiddle link. I created a moving spinner with css. But black part which is spinning/moving should have rounded edges. Can't get it from what I have now.

```
.loader {
    position: relative;
    border-top: 10px solid #805da4;
    border-right: 10px solid #805da4;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #805da4;
    border-left: 10px solid #000;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
    -webkit-animation-name: spinner;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: You'd need SVG for that...

Comment: Is there any way to do this without SVG, please? @Paulie_D

Comment: You cannot change "black part" borders, because it's already a border itself (left border before start transforming)

Comment: Nope, not really...`<canvas>` maybe but not with borders like that.

Comment: @Paulie_D, now please check my answer.. I achieve it without SVG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in HTML code

```
<div class="highlightRoundBox">
<span class="loading">
<span class="edge edge-left"></span>
<span class="edge edge-right"></span>
</span>
</div>
```

in CSS code

```
@keyframes spin {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
.highlightRoundBox {
    position: relative;
    margin: 11px 27px 13px 6px;
    width:68px;
    height: 68px;
}
.loading {
  display:block;
  position:relative;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0.5rem solid #805da4;
    border-top-color: #000;
    animation: spin 1s infinite linear;
}
.loading .edge {
  display:block;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 0.5rem;
  height: 0.5rem;
  background:#000;
}
.loading .edge.edge-left
{
   top:0.22rem;
  left:0.2rem;
}
.loading .edge.edge-right
{
  top:0.20em;
  right:0.22em;
}
```

check link https://jsfiddle.net/4yL3rp38/22/

Comment: where are rounded edges of black border. I don't see rounded edges @Haresh Vidja

Comment: But it isn't working. Can you please check your fiddle? I don't see any move? @Haresh Vidja

Comment: and where are rounded corners? I still don't see. @Haresh Vidja

Comment: Hello madam, in your fiddle link, I didin't see any rounded corner except rounded circle.  can you share your screendhot?

Comment: Exactly that was my question, if you read my question you will see. I need that black moving spinner to be rounded. Please read my question carefully @Haresh Vidja

Comment: @aidaghazaryan, I have added two dots on border edge... not it looks like what you need check it.. https://jsfiddle.net/4yL3rp38/19/

Thanks..:)

Comment: ohh thanks. Yes, now it is what I want. I was wondering can we make it to play every 10 second and not always? What do you think? @Haresh Vidja

Comment: @aidaghazaryan, Glade to hear your positive reply.. i think without stop it looks good.  ... you can change it  animation: spin 1s infinite linear; and please dont forget to up vote and mark as correct.. thanks in advance.. :)

Comment: No, see I mean to repeat that moving every 10second. I'm not talking about the speed. @Haresh Vidja

Comment: Unfortunately , Stack Overflow is for only get solution what you ask not for changes what you think. I can assist only here, I cant provide whole solution here. Sorry.